# Springboot JPA - Call a function on a property when the entity is retrieved from DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using spring boot with hibernate for my application. My application has some sensitive data, so they are stored in encrypted form in the database.

However, my application wants them decrypted. Normally this is done via a procedure in database. In plain old SQL, this can be done without a problem.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@Data
@Component
public class myObject implements Serializable
{
    //This is stored in DB decrypted. I want this to be decrypted when I fetch the records.
    @Column(name = "sensitive_data")
    private String sensitiveData;

    //Other unrelated properties
}
```

I can do this decryption after the object is loaded to my application as I have posted below. However, this will be leading to more and more DB calls for each object I need.Also this will slow down my application. So I thought of finding a way to get decrypted value this while loading my object from database.

```
@Repository
public interface myRepo extends JpaRepository<myObject , String>
{
    //(1)I use this for getting the list of objects from database
    @Query("SELECT obj FROM myObject obj WHERE obj.statusCode =:status_code ")
    List<myObject> getmyObjects(@Param("status_code") String status_code);

    //(2)I use this to get decrypted value after when I perform operations on objects received from (1)
    @Procedure("decrypt_function")
    String getDecrptedValue(@Param("encrypted") String encrypted);
}
```

To be clear, `sensitive_data` column will have a value like '212AFD232323DGGFF'. But I need the decrypted value by calling `decrypt_function` at the time of object loading from the database.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can use [JPA 2.1 AttributeConverters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-jpa-convert).

Comment: @SternK Thanks.. But I need something different. The column value in DB is encrypted. I just wanna have decrypted value to be stored in my java variable.

Comment: Are you going to update this variable? If no, you can try to use [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula)

Comment: Maybe `@ColumnTransformer` helps, but I've never word with it.
Offtopic: Have a look at magic JPA queries. You don't need the `@Query` annotation for this. Instead you can use `List<myObject> findByStatusCode(String statusCode)`.

Comment: SternK @Formula was the way to go. Thanks